# Track custom firefox search engine with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, opensearch

I made a custom Firefox search engine. It used the code below. Is it possible for me to track the use of this on the site. My concern is that searches form the firefox search engine will look like direct visits in google analytics. I would like to tag the searches or some other solution. I kinda hacked this together i.e. a newbie at this.

```
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<ShortName>ICD9 Code Search</ShortName>
<Description>Search ICD9 Code Search</Description>
<Tags>schadenfreude</Tags>
<Image height="16" width="16" type="image/x-icon">https://drchrono.com/favicon.ico</Image>
<Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="https://drchrono.com/billing/medical_codes/?code_type=icd9_procedures&amp;search_text={searchTerms}&amp;Submit=Search&amp;search_hcpcs_level2_codes=on&amp;search_hcpcs_level2_modifiers=on"/>
<InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
<AdultContent>false</AdultContent>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you not add a dummy query parameter that does not affect behaviour but can be used when analysing logs? E.g.:

```
<Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="https://drchrono.com/billing/medical_codes/?code_type=icd9_procedures&amp;search_text={searchTerms}&amp;Submit=Search&amp;search_hcpcs_level2_codes=on&amp;search_hcpcs_level2_modifiers=on&amp;source=firefox_se"/>
```

Comment: Not sure, I will try that. Then try to discover if it worked.

Comment: That does not seem to work, It still searches correctly but nothing is getting tracked in google analytics, I gave it several days to show the results but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called campaign tagging. You can append special arguments to the URL that will be recognized by the Google Analytics script running on your site and collected on GA's *Traffic Sources/Campaigns* report. There is an online [URL builder tool by Google](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55578) that helps you creating the campaign tags.

Comment: when I tag the url with using the url builder Firefox no longer find it an acceptable plugin and will not install it. I am not clear what the rules of this game are.

Comment: @Vincent try only appending the `utm_*` paramteres to the end of the URL you already use in the XML.